# Is there a synonym for the word "revive" other than "resurrect/raise from death"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

Imagine a person lying down on the floor, dead. A moment later he/she breaths again. Is there any other word to describe this scene other than "revived" or "resurrected" or "raised from death"?

The reasons I'm looking for another words are, I already used "revive" in my writing and resurrect/raise from death gives me a negative feeling like the character becomes a zombie.

I want to describe a miraculous incident but it's not a powerful moment like a dragon or a sorcerer raising from death, just a human being starts to breath again. It's a spontaneous happening without any external help like medical intervention. He simply comes back to life without resuscitation.

Comment: Well, resuscitate comes to mind....

Comment: This puts a smile on my face. "Is there any other word to describe this other than all these other words that I am listing myself right now". Well. I guess one answer could be, use any of these many words that you using as we speak.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "exact synonym".

Comment: (And yes, of course there are other words for this, like *resuscitate, reanimate, requicken* even. *Bring back to life*. Whatever. But really you need to specify your criteria for dismissing words because all the words you've got are perfectly fine already, and so we can't be sure you won't just as easily dismiss any of the perfectly fine words that we supplement.)

Comment: Why not use the perfectly good phrase 'come back to life', which appears within the question itself? Is it because it is not a single word? Why is it important that the term be a single word?

Comment: We may be hard-pressed to find a word that describes what you're trying to capture while at the same time excludes any zombie connotations, given the prevalence of zombie pop culture over the last decade especially. Writers may have exhausted all the single-word synonyms there are for "coming back to life" in their zombie stories. Also, it seems like you're wanting to stay away from _transitive verbs_, as the coming back to life just _happens_ rather than being the result of another entity's action.

Answer (score 0):

From the last part of your question (I assum that you edited it to provide clarification):

> It's a spontaneous happening without any external help like medical intervention. He simply comes back to life without resuscitation.

I'm going to come right out and say, "No, there is no such word." It happens so infrequently that nothing has been coined for such an event.

In looking at various news stories about such occurrences, either people were found to have not been dead in the first place (they were misdiagnosed) or people simply said that they **came back from the dead** (because there is no other way of expressing it).

---

The only word that even comes close (and it's only a figurative match) is [reborn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reborn).

> born again : REGENERATED, REVIVED

Only in speculative fiction, however, could *regenerated* actually express something meaningful. (And I know you don't want the *revived* sense.)

Comment: Not really related to the answer as such, but does ‘dead’ really count as a (mis)diagnosis? Sounds a bit odd to think of someone as having been diagnosed with death.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Apparently it's been known to happen. Like [this guy](https://www.livescience.com/61385-man-declared-dead-really-alive.html) who was declared dead by three doctors but who (thankfully) started snoring at the start of his autopsy. Or [this boy](https://www.aol.com/article/news/2017/02/21/teenager-wakes-up-headed-to-his-own-funeral-after-being-presumed/21718716/) who woke up in a coffin on the way to his funeral. Or [this man](http://www.ladbible.com/news/weird-news-man-wakes-up-during-open-casket-funeral-leaves-family-terrified-20171027) who woke up at his own funeral. :)

Comment: (Some of these could be hoaxes, although I doubt all of them are.)

Comment: Oh yes, I know it happens—it’s the word ‘diagnosis’ I found odd. Declared dead, pronounced dead, sure. But diagnosed with death?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh! Yes. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**resuscitate**  [TFD](https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/resuscitate)

> to restore to consciousness; revive

As in:

> A moment later he/she **resuscitated,** breathing and moving again again.

If you insist:  [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/submission/6115/autoresuscitation) **autoresuscitation** as in autoresuscitated.  Also know as the *Lazarus Syndrome*.